# Can Excel read from .Rdata or .RDS flies?

Tags: r, excel, rdata

Is this possible (preferably without needing to have an R session running at the same time)? I’ve searched online but I can’t see any mention of it...so perhaps not.

Many thanks

Comment: There are libraries that allow you to export from R to xlsx. `xlsx` for example has the `write.xlsx` function.

Comment: Thank you, but alas the objects are too big (too many rows) to fit into Excel. I suppose I’d like to be able to query the R data from inside Excel (eg by using pivot tables) but it seems it can’t be done.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are in a data frame, write it to a text file with **write.table**. Use tab as column separator, and it will likely load directly into a spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks. Yes I do that sometimes for small data sets but I’m playing with data frames with >1M rows at the moment so they won’t fit. In those cases I’m putting them in an Access DB file instead (and then interrogating in Excel using a pivot table pointing at the DB) but that’s very slow and Access wastes a lot of space. Wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Playing with huge datasets in Excel is no fun. It seems you need another tool. How about exporting from R to  an open-source DB? There must be R packages that allows you to do that directly. You would then need to learn how to use the open-source DB, though, to reach a level that allows playing with data.